# Is there must use ViewModel in un-rotate app

Tags: android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

If my app set screenOrientation portrait, so ViewModel is suitable for me ?
or just use for divide ui and logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Having a proper architecture might be useful in terms of testability, extendability of the app let it be: MVP, MVVM.

In case of MVVM, using ViewModel helps you to handle configure changes not only screen rotation but also other cases like multi-window mode in a lifecycle-aware way as well as it would be helpful separate UI and business logic. By doing so, your codebase will be easy to work with and to make changes on.

There is no "must" in terms of choosing an architecture but it is strongly recommended to have an architecture.